# How do I enable the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access a Google Sheet using the API. There is a button on this page named "Enable the Google Sheet API", but whenever I click it, it just loads forever. Is there another way to enable the API and download `credentials.json`? Is the button working?

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs?authuser=1

Comment: How about the following flow? If that is not what you want, I apologize. 1. Open [API console](https://console.cloud.google.com). 2. At Getting started, click "Explore and enable APIs". 3. At left side, click "Credentials". 4. Create credentials and OAuth client ID. Here, select "Other" as a test. Click Create. 5. Download JSON which is ``credentials.json``. 6. At left side, click "Library". 7. At Search for APIs & services, input "sheets". And click "Google Sheets API". 8. Click "Enable". If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can enable it from within the [Google Console Dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard), and [manage your credentials]([Google Console Dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)) too.

There should be a button on the dashboard at the top that says "Enable APIs and Services"